# Trim function in Linq GroupBy statement

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to GroupBy element using a field (CompteNum) that has space in it. So I would like to trim the field using this code

```
    var excelLinesGrouped = excelLines
                           .GroupBy(l => l.CompteNum.Trim(),
                           (entry, elements) =>
                           new
                             {
                             Entry = entry,
                             Writings = elements
                             });
```

It gives null results probably meaning that trim is not supported in GroupBy. Is there any alternative for this?

Thanks

Comment: this should work. please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I agree, it should work. Trim is being applied to CompteNum as well, so it's irrelevant to GroupBy support.

Comment: `.Trim()` is supported. It would take something like: `"some "` and `"some"` and `" some"` and group the three together because it's grouping by the trimmed value (as you expect).

Comment: I have to be more precise "excelLines" comes from LinqToExcel
`code`
 var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(myExcelFileName);
 var excelLines = (from line in excel.Worksheet<MyLineData>("Sheet") select line).ToList();

Thanks for you help

Comment: If it is not supported by LinqToExcel, then an alternative is to pull the data with a `.ToList()`, and then do your `.GroupBy`, effectively doing the group by in the LinqToObject space.